# rvm install 2.7.4 Error running '__rvm_make -j8'

Tags: ruby, rvm, apple-m1

I'm rather lost and cannot understand why my install is failing.

Here is the output of `rvm install 2.7.4 --debug` from where I think the install starts to fail.

```
Log file: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/log/1688419933_ruby-2.7.4/extract.log
[2023-07-03 17:32:36] __rvm_package_extract
__rvm_package_extract () {
    rvm_debug __rvm_package_extract:$#: "$@"
    \typeset __extract_src __extract_target __tempdir __path __file __return
    __extract_src="$1" 
    __extract_target="$2" 
    shift 2
    __return=0 
    __tempdir="$( TMPDIR="${rvm_tmp_path}" mktemp -d -t rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX )" 
    __rvm_package_extract_run "$__extract_src" "$__tempdir" "$@" || __return=$? 
    if (( __return == 0 ))
    then
        for __path in "$__tempdir"/*
        do
            __file="${__path##*/}" 
            if [[ -n "${__file}" && -e "$__extract_target/${__file}" ]]
            then
                \command \rm -rf "$__extract_target/${__file}" || __return=$? 
            fi
            \command \mv -f "${__path}" "$__extract_target/" || __return=$? 
        done
    fi
    if [[ -n "$__tempdir" ]]
    then
        \command \rm -rf "$__tempdir"
    fi
    return $__return
}
current path: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/src
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=
GEM_PATH=
command(3): __rvm_package_extract /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.7.4.tar.bz2 /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_7513
ruby-2.7.4 - #extracting ruby-2.7.4 to /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.4 - please wait
__rvm_package_extract:2: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.7.4.tar.bz2 /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_7513
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.4
Patch name 'optional', expanded_name(s) ''.
Patch name 'default', expanded_name(s) ''.
Patch name 'osx', expanded_name(s) ''.
All found patches(0): .
Log file: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/log/1688419933_ruby-2.7.4/configure.log
[2023-07-03 17:32:39] ./configure
current path: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.4
PATH=/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=
GEM_PATH=
command(6): ./configure --prefix=/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4  --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/zlib:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
ruby-2.7.4 - #configuring - please wait
Log file: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/log/1688419933_ruby-2.7.4/postconfigure.log
[2023-07-03 17:34:11] __rvm_post_configure_ruby
__rvm_post_configure_ruby () {
    __rvm_post_configure_ruby_fix_athlon_sse2
    __rvm_post_configure_ruby_update_setup
}
current path: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.4
PATH=/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=
GEM_PATH=
command(1): __rvm_post_configure_ruby
ruby-2.7.4 - #post-configuration - please wait
Log file: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/log/1688419933_ruby-2.7.4/make.log
[2023-07-03 17:34:11] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () {
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.4
PATH=/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=
GEM_PATH=
command(2): __rvm_make -j8
ruby-2.7.4 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/log/1688419933_ruby-2.7.4/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /Users/ryanhorowitz/.rvm/tmp/7513*
```

I am using an M1 mac. I am not sure what else I should include.
If anyone could help me that would be most appreciated.
Is there any other code I should be including? please let me know.

Thank you very much.

I have tried reinstalling RVM and Homebrew. I have tried :

1. `rvm get head && rvm reinstall 2.7.4 --debug`
2. from this trouble shoot thread for the same error [rvm issues](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5043)

- Right click Terminal from the Application/Utilities folder, Get Info, tick the "Open using Rosetta" box.
- Uninstall Homebrew
  ``` /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL ``https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh``)" ```
  `rm -rf /opt/homebrew/*`
  `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew`
- Reinstall Homebrew
  ``` /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL ``https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh``)" ```
- Restart terminal
- Check Homebrew is working fine: `brew doctor`
- Reinstall openssl: `brew install openssl` `rvm install 2.7`

3. I have also updated my xcode in the process

Expecting Ruby 2.7.4 to install

Comment: This may or may not have any bearing on what you're seeing. But in the past I've found that there is a login, or verification, or terms of use agreement, that needs to be executed in Xcode before it can be used. This has caused me problems in the past as it's not flagged in the compilation error. The fix is to open Xcode... you will be prompted for some action if this is your problem.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you installed the latest version of MacPorts and setup its path?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you typed... you weren't using "arch -arm64". I was having the exact same problem you were:

[Error running '__rvm_make -j8' RVM install on OSX Ventura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928819/error-running-rvm-make-j8-rvm-install-on-osx-ventura?noredirect=1#comment135623497_76928819)

You have to do that for both the install of Homebrew AND the rvm install of Ruby if you have the M1 chip.  As a matter of fact you might as well use it for all non-common (common being "mv" or "cp" or "rm") commands.

I don't see anywhere above where you used it.

Therefore:

```
arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

followed by...

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

then followed by:

```
arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Should do the trick.

After that it's just a simple matter of:

```
arch -arm64 rvm install 2.7.4
```