# Error running '__rvm_make -j8' RVM install on OSX Ventura

Tags: ruby, rvm, macos-ventura

Since it's literally been months now I figured I'd finally just get on here and ask.  I can't install any version of Ruby at all using RVM on MacOS Ventura. It doesn't seem to be related to problems that other people have had with this. I've tried all the other solutions. But this doesn't seem to be related to OpenSSL or anything like that.

The error I receive is also a bit different than those cases:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8'
```

For starters... here's the last few lines of the log I get when I run: rvm install 2.6.10

```
objspace.c:630:23: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        imemo_type_ids[10] = rb_intern("imemo_parser_strterm");
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1826:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
objspace.c:630:23: note: '{' token is here
        imemo_type_ids[10] = rb_intern("imemo_parser_strterm");
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1811:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
objspace.c:630:23: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
        imemo_type_ids[10] = rb_intern("imemo_parser_strterm");
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1826:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1816:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
objspace.c:630:23: note: ')' token is here
        imemo_type_ids[10] = rb_intern("imemo_parser_strterm");
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1826:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                       ^
1342 warnings generated.
linking shared-object objspace.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

I've also installed the latest version of macports (and got its path working correctly) uninstalled and reinstalled OpenSSL. Uninstalled and Reinstalled HomeBrew multiple times... Nothing seems to help.

**UPDATE: This is the one error I could find.**

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
```

I searched the logs high and low but couldn't find the second error.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4370#issuecomment-407138297. Looking through [Others](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) experiencing the same or similar issues it appears to be related to openssl1 and openssl3 compatibility issues.

Comment: Yeah, like I said I tried all the OpenSSL stuff. I've done: "Which openssl" to find out where mine was and made sure I was running that version... but none of those solutions seemed to work. Which leads me to believe my problem must be different. Mine is just like this guy's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76608323/rvm-install-2-7-4-error-running-rvm-make-j8 and he never got a solution either...

Comment: in the other solutions which are usually like "error running rvm make j1" (this one is j8) you usually see OpenSSL all over the logs... That's nowhere in my logs or the other guy's.

Comment: Those log file entries are warnings. Somewhere there should be an actual error that makes the compilation fail. That's the one which gives a better hint.

Comment: But it LOOKS like it could perhaps be a compiler incompatibility issue. Macs use clang while many others use GCC.

Comment: Well what can I do about that?  How do I choose which compiler macos is using?

Comment: Here's the one error I could find: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'?
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be difficult discerning exactly what I did to solve this problem. But I'll do my best to backtrace.

**1. Uninstalled Homebrew**

```
arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

If you're using an M1 chip then you **MUST** use the arch -arm64 ahead of every command otherwise it WILL fail.

**2. Deleted ALL Remaining Homebrew Directories**

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

**3. Reinstalled Homebrew**

```
arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

The reason for uninstalling Homebrew and getting rid of all its directories is that, if you're like me, you probably tried a MILLION things on your path to getting this to work. Removing Homebrew and its associated directories should wipe out any mistakes you may have made or desperate configuration gambles. To be sure though... you should look for hidden configuration files to make sure none of them reference Ruby.

**4. Use rvm To Install Ruby**

```
arch -arm64 rvm install 3.2.2
```

Again you MUST use "arch -arm64" or your install will absolutely fail. Only this time with an Error Code of "1" instead of "2".

That was it! Install completed. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  brew install openssl
  rvm install 2.6.10 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question... This isn't an OpenSSL issue. I did  try that actually... It just didn't work because it's not an OpenSSL problem. The problem is, if you're using an M1 chip, you have to preface everything with arch -arm64 if your terminal isn't already setup that way. Otherwise anything that uses compiler will fail